# Single query that switches between databases based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

We have a situation where we have two versions of the same database on two seperate servers - one for each of two sites. It is currently not feasible to bring them together into one database for many reasons.

We have many SSRS reports but each one is duplicated for each database so we would like to have one report that takes a locationID and gets the data from the appropriate database.

The obvious way is of course to have an "IF" on the locationID then duplicate the code changing only the "FROM" clause, however this is in my opinion a ridonculously bad way of doing things.

Is there any way that we could put a conditional statement on the "FROM" part of an SQL query behind the report?

We have tried other ways (Table valued functions, Replication) but the performance and speed is always unacceptable. (two reports take ~2 seconds to load - 1 report with Table Valued Functions take >40 seconds)

(I would also like to add that it was not my idea to have them on seperate servers and we cant change that now.)

Comment: Is Dynamic SQL an option to allow you to control the FROM?

Comment: We have talked about that but my manager is under the impression that it is too complex and unmaintainable. (not an opinion I agree with)

Comment: This is what is wrong in the world of programming (specifically the business end of things), too many non-IT people making decisions on design and what is and isn't a good option?! Pffff!

Comment: You could also argue the opposite case: too many non business valued decisions are made by technical people! :)

Comment: In the words of Penny from Big Bang Theory - "Come on guys *claps hand* Focus - I got a problem here!"

Comment: @StevenWood - Dynamic SQL CAN be unmaintanable if written badly (true of ANY code/approach). If you cannot convince your manager, then obviously it is off the table as an option. Personally, I'd knock something up to demonstrate it and also show them the nice neat code

Answer (score 0):

Just separate out the datasets and create a table/matrix/graph for each? You can just add a second data source, have identical query/SP in the datasets and point each dataset to the respective servers.

Or maybe I'm just not seeing the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using SSRS and so are limited in options, the following is a dirty hack but might work for your predicament:

```
-- assumes @useDB1 bit field of 1 or 0
SELECT
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3
FROM (
    -- db1 table(s)
    SELECT * FROM Table1 T
    WHERE T.PrimaryKeyField IS NULL OR @useDB1 = 1

    UNION ALL

    -- db2 linked server
    SELECT * FROM [db2Link].DatabaseName.dbo.Table1 T
    WHERE T.PrimaryKeyField IS NULL OR @useDB1 = 0
) DB
-- other filters/grouping here
WHERE SomeOtherField = @someOtherParameter
```

The sub-query will return no rows for one of the databases depending on the parameter. I checked if the query optimizer will handle this cleanly, and was sorely disappointed that it does select all fields, though at least the outer-query WHERE clause was used to limit the number of rows returned.

If the tables aren't too wide, or you need all the fields anyway, then there's little impact of the above from my very brief tests.

If you need a sub-set of fields or joins on multiple tables, consider creating a view on both databases to simplify this so you can still use `SELECT *`.

Comment: This is most definitely a dirty hack, but also one of the few ways to achieve this functionality, and definitely the easiest.  One thing I'd recommend:  instead of a bunch of union'd selects, make 1 stored procedure per target server, and have a master procedure call the appropriate child sproc depending on the incoming parameters.